# Keeping background image fixed with responsive design

Tags: html, css, web

If you take a look here:

https://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//logan-gabriel.com&w=1600&h=900&a=1&s=1

There's a small white margin on the right side of the screen. This shouldn't be the case, as the background image should be fixed all the right to the right edge. If you try the other smaller resolutions, you'll notice this is the behavior. But once the screen gets to this large of a width (1600px), it fails.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks guys.

Comment: have u tried the below CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Hey set image width to auto

```
#image 
{
width:auto;//you have set 40% which causes the issue
}
```

Comment: this works when horizontally expanding the image, but gets rid of the fluid layout of my page so when smaller screens use it the content on the left cannot be seen because the background is covering it up.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the followig

```
#image {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


#image img {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: interesting effect, but not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to change the width to auto once the screen gets into the the "large" size

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1430px){
    #image{
        width:auto;
        }
    }
```